# Meaning of 又把聚会当做一次分手

Tags: meaning, lyrics

Hi I'm trying to figure out what the lyrics of mean of 思 念.

The last sentence is

又把聚会当做一次分手

However, the grammar is a tad difficult and I'm struggling to make sense of it.

My interpretations:
Again, treat our meeting as goodbye?
As soon as we met again, it's goodbye?

Can someone explain it to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretations is quite right.

The lyrics means:

```
Even though we met again, but soon we separate again.
It should be treated as a goodbye, rather than a meeting.
```

Comment: cool thanks.. asked my teacher about it today, she explained it as meaning a kind of breakup meeting (as in when a couple split up)

Answer (score 0):

It means, 尽管你同意和我见面,但是你和我一见面之后就要分手(Although you wish to see me again, but as soon as our meeting is over, you coldly leave me without a message).